# Ubuntu install not working

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation

I've recently changed my OS on the laptop from Ubuntu 14.04 to windows 10 preview build. Now, when I'm trying to clean install the Ubuntu 14.04 back on my laptop I'm unable to do so. When I plugin my bootable USB/CD and select "install Ubuntu" it doesn't boot in. The boot doesn't load and the screen keeps flickering.

How do I fix this? How to find out what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you set your BIOS to boot from the ODD (in case of CD/DVD) or USB ( in case of a thumb drive ) ? try setting that if u didn't...
and before you boot into the disk shutdown windows 10 a full shutdown ( because it mainly uses hibernate when shut down)

To do a full shut down you can simply type into the Windows CMD: `shutdown -s -t 0`

then boot up from the disk

if non of this worked make a new bootable image and boot from it... it might be a corrupt image !

Comment: You don't have to make the BIOS boot to the DVD/CD/USB/Whatever thing you use, that's basically a useless addition beacuse we all have a option called the boot menu allowing for us to boot into USB, CD, DVD (ODD doesn't exist) and etc. directly.

Comment: ODD = Optical Disk Drive. And one can either change boot order or use the boot menu, both works. But it should be mentioned though.

Comment: I've tried installing Ubuntu using different techniques like installing after a complete shutdown, or Running Ubuntu Live and then completely unmounted the HDD and partitioned it using 'GParted' for fresh install. Also, ISO is corrupt because I've used the same image before successfully. Besides I've tried to create a bootable USB/CD multiple times by using different ISO's that I've downloaded multiple times.

Comment: I Know there is a boot menu, and I know what ODD is, if I didn't I won't have mentioned it !!! I am not a noob... sorry to not mention anything about the boot menu.... anyway I've been working in a computer repairs shop since I were 14 !!! 

back to solutions... did you mark your partition of the bootable drive as active ??? I don't think this will do much !!! just try that !!!